# Log4Net: Logging in 2 byte languages (japanese, chinese etc.)

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I would like to log data to a file in 2 byte languages (chinese, japanese etc) using log4net.

How to properly configure log4net to do that?

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) - Unicode doesn't always mean 2 bytes.

Comment: @Kragen agree. I'm interested in the 2 bytes case. See examples I gave.

Comment: So you mean UTF-16? (UTF-8 is more common nowadays)

Comment: @Kragen How to configure log4net to handle any encoding I want?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The log file encoding is specified by [FileAppender.Encoding](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Appender_FileAppender_Encoding.htm). It can be configured using the `encoding` configuration element. Example:

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="file.log" />
    <encoding value="utf-8" />
    ...
```

The value is the code page name. The corresponding Encoding is obtained using the [`System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a3kf7c.aspx) method. For a list of code pages, see the Encoding class [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx).

Comment: In my projet we're currently using `<encoding value="unicodeFFFE" />`