# log4net works well in window 10 but only wirte part of logs in windows 7 and xp

Tags: .net, windows, unicode, log4net, log4net-configuration

I use log4net to log info and error in my application, it works well in windows 10, but in windows 7 and windows xp, it only write part of the logs, looks like below

[image]

This is my log4net config, anyone can help?

```
<log4net>
  <logger name="logerror">
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="ErrorAppender" />
  </logger>
  <logger name="loginfo">
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="InfoAppender" />
  </logger>
  <appender name="ErrorAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="Log\\LogError\\" />
    <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
    <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="100" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10240" />
    <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyyMMdd&quot;.htm&quot;" />
    <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="&lt;HR COLOR=red&gt;%n异常时间：%d [%t] &lt;BR&gt;%n异常级别：%-5p &lt;BR&gt;%n异 常 类：%c [%x] &lt;BR&gt;%n%m &lt;BR&gt;%n &lt;HR Size=1&gt;"  />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="InfoAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="Log\\LogInfo\\" />
    <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10240" />
    <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="100" />
    <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyyMMdd&quot;.htm&quot;" />
    <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="&lt;HR COLOR=blue&gt;%n日志时间：%d [%t] &lt;BR&gt;%n日志级别：%-5p &lt;BR&gt;%n日 志 类：%c [%x] &lt;BR&gt;%n%m &lt;BR&gt;%n &lt;HR Size=1&gt;"  />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

Comment: log4net is an old library. Obviously, it works in Windows 7 and even unsupported ancient OSs like Windows XP. What is the screenshot supposed to show? What is the *actual* problem and how do you write to the log?  What do you mean `it only write part of the logs` ?

Comment: Are you referring to the question marks? `?` or `�` are used when an invalid codepage conversion is attempted. This could mean that you tried to convert ASCII text to Unicode using an invalid codepage. **App.config itself** may be stored as ASCII instead of UTF8, in which case the conversion pattern itself will result in  bad conversions. If you intend to store non-ASCII text in `app.config` you have to ensure it's saved as UTF8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log4Net: Logging in 2 byte languages (japanese, chinese etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953424/log4net-logging-in-2-byte-languages-japanese-chinese-etc)

Comment: Post the *actual* output. The conversion pattern contains HTML tags. I fhte message started with `<!--` the log would be written correctly, but everything after `[` would be invisible when rendered as HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you refer to the `?` characters. `?` and `�` are replacement characters that are used when an invalid codepage conversion is attempted, eg from Unicode to a codepage that can't handle all the characters. For example, trying to write Japanese or Chinese characters to a file using the Latin-1 codepage will replace all non-Latin characters with `?` or `�`.

This seems to be the problem here. By default, log4net uses the [Default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3td5yce6?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) encoding, which correspond's to system's locale, to write to files.

You can specify the encoding explicitly with the [FileAppender.Encoding](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Appender_FileAppender_Encoding.htm) property:

```
<appender name="ErrorAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoding value = "utf-8" />

<appender name="InfoAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoding value = "utf-8" />
```

Comment: Hi @Panagiotis, thanks for your reply. it doesn't related to encoding, even change the encoding, the content still doesn't been write. You can see only '[' display after 'loginfo', it should contain other content after '['. For example, [Login successfully].

Comment: @Allen4Tech explain what's wrong in the question itself and include actual code that rerproduces the problem . One can only guess what you mean. The question marks are *definitely* related to encoding.

Comment: @Allen4Tech and post the *actual* output, not the screenshot. Your pattern contains HTML characters. The output values may result in invalid HTML. Imagine what would happen eg if the message started with `<!-- `. `log4net` would still output the correct log record but it would be invisible in a browser